# Text out of the box for the validation

Tags: jquery, css, validation, jquery-tools

I am following this tutorial [here](http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/validator/index.html) to use the validator of Jquery-Tools .

But why does the validation text appear out of the yellow box?, I have tried to play with CSS but it didn't work:

[image]

Does any one have an idea?

Comment: OK...fixed by adding .error p {
    margin:0;
}

Comment: put that in an answer , and accept your own answer

Answer (score 2):

OK...fixed by adding .error p { margin:0; }